# rocm not detecting radeon rx 480 as agent

Tags: amdgpu

```
root@gpt:/home# lshw -C display
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: c7
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
resources: irq:41 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
root@gpt:/home# lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev c7)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1458:22df]
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

```
root@gpt:/home/q# lsmod | grep amdgpu
amdgpu              13590528  0
amddrm_ttm_helper      16384  1 amdgpu
amdttm                 94208  2 amdgpu,amddrm_ttm_helper
amdxcp                 16384  1 amdgpu
iommu_v2               24576  1 amdgpu
amddrm_buddy           20480  1 amdgpu
amd_sched              49152  1 amdgpu
amdkcl                 32768  3 amd_sched,amdttm,amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        307200  2 amdgpu
drm                   618496  9 drm_kms_helper,amd_sched,amdttm,amdgpu,amddrm_buddy,amdkcl,amddrm_ttm_helper,amdxcp
```

```
root@gpt:/home/q# rocminfo
ROCk module is loaded
=====================
HSA System Attributes
=====================
Runtime Version:         1.1
System Timestamp Freq.:  1000.000000MHz
Sig. Max Wait Duration:  18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) (timestamp count)
Machine Model:           LARGE
System Endianness:       LITTLE
Mwaitx:                  DISABLED
DMAbuf Support:          YES

==========
HSA Agents
==========
*******
Agent 1
*******
  Name:                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
  Uuid:                    CPU-XX
  Marketing Name:          AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
  Vendor Name:             CPU
  Feature:                 None specified
  Profile:                 FULL_PROFILE
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR
  Max Queue Number:        0(0x0)
  Queue Min Size:          0(0x0)
  Queue Max Size:          0(0x0)
  Queue Type:              MULTI
  Node:                    0
  Device Type:             CPU
  Cache Info:
    L1:                      16384(0x4000) KB
  Chip ID:                 0(0x0)
  ASIC Revision:           0(0x0)
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   4000
  BDFID:                   0
  Internal Node ID:        0
  Compute Unit:            8
  SIMDs per CU:            0
  Shader Engines:          0
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   0
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:1
  Features:                None
  Pool Info:
    Pool 1
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: FINE GRAINED
      Size:                    32718068(0x1f33cf4) KB
      Allocatable:             TRUE
      Alloc Granule:           4KB
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB
      Accessible by all:       TRUE
    Pool 2
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: KERNARG, FINE GRAINED
      Size:                    32718068(0x1f33cf4) KB
      Allocatable:             TRUE
      Alloc Granule:           4KB
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB
      Accessible by all:       TRUE
    Pool 3
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED
      Size:                    32718068(0x1f33cf4) KB
      Allocatable:             TRUE
      Alloc Granule:           4KB
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB
      Accessible by all:       TRUE
  ISA Info:
*** Done ***
```